# Automatic GridView Controls

Tags: asp.net, .net

In my project i have several GridViews, all of which have somehow automatically put in edit, cancel and paging functionality that i have been able to add to if i wished. However on one of them none of the buttons link up. always comes out with a Not Handled Exception.

I sorted this out earlier in the week, but due to source control it reverted back and is now not recoverable. I can't remember what i changed to get it working and have had no joy in finding out from google etc, so thought i'd post it and try and find out if anyone else knows.

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to make sure that the CellContentClick event is being handled on that grid?